# docker container jupyter lab, how to add other packages?

Tags: python, docker

I'm using docker for deep learning. and i'm super beginner as docker user.
ubuntu 18.04
docker version 19.03.6
and i got ufoym/deepo image. so i'm using jupyter lab in web.
container 1 : jupyter lab
container 2 : vscode

question
1. if i want to use other python packages(like matplotlib basemap toolkits, hdbscan,folium that doesn't contain in ufoym/deepo image) , how can i install and build those packages?
2. in jupyter lab, when i do (e.g) !pip install foium, then where is the installed directory ??
and is it the right way to use (pip install?) in docker system?

please help me~

Comment: By the way, the modern way to do `!pip install` in your notebook is `%pip install <package_name>`. See [here](https://twitter.com/jakevdp/status/1139213090745020416). It will insure it does things right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you absolutely can use `pip` inside the docker container.
The [official Python Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) actually already comes with `pip` preinstalled.

The usual way `pip` is used in the container is by placing a `requirements.txt` in your project folder, the one that will then be mapped inside the container.
In your `Dockefile` you should then add these lines to install the packages.

```
COPY requirements.txt <path to the folder your app will live inside the container>
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```